# How do I kill a Python multiprocessing job?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, redhat, python-multiprocessing

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802503/python-multiprocessing-doesnt-seem-to-use-more-than-one-core) I had asked, I can successfully run jobs using multiprocessing and I can see that all processors are being utilized.
How do I kill this job?
From terminal I run:

```
python my_multiprocessor_script.py
```

Then I hit `Ctrl+C` to kill.

However the job doesn't seem to be killed and I can see all the processors still in use.
I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6.

Comment: `sudo pkill -9 python` should do the trick

Comment: @JoranBeasley: you are fast...

Comment: Any way to do it without sudo?

Comment: you probably dont need sudo assuming it launches under the same user you are running as

Comment: and multiprocessing should launch under the same user, so you don't need sudo

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do something like this.

[Original Author](http://www.oracleflash.com/20/How-to-kill-all-processes-with-one-command-in-Linux.html)

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep my_multiprocessor_script.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

also take a look at [Python Multiprocessing Kill Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18477541/1380867)  for more info